# Segmentation fault on fscanf

Tags: c, segmentation-fault, scanf, ppm

I'm wrriting a program to store PPM files and I am stuck with passing in the rgb values. The first fscanf in the loop causes a segementation fault, and the test printf line before it doesn't print. I've tried with the "temp" variable as an int and there was still the same issue.

(The rest of the program I haven't included as it's irrelevant to the question)

```
typedef struct{
    unsigned char r, g, b;
} pixel;

typedef struct{
    int width, height, max;
    pixel *rgbdata;
} PPM;

static PPM * getPPM(FILE * f) {

    printf("start getppm\n");

    char line[100];
    PPM *image;
    char temp[7];
    int rval, gval, bval;
    int counter;

    image = (PPM *)malloc(sizeof(PPM));
    printf("memory alloc\n");

    fgets(line, sizeof(line), f);
    if(line[0]!='P' || line[1]!='3'){
        fprintf(stderr, "File is not correct PPM format \n");
        exit(1);
    }
    printf("valid PPM file\n");

    do{
        fgets(line, sizeof(line), f);   
    }while(line[0]=='#');

    fscanf(f, "%d %d", &image->width, &image->height);
    fscanf(f, "%d", &image->max);

    image->rgbdata = (pixel*)malloc(image->width * image->height * sizeof(pixel));

    printf("pixel memory alloc\n");

    do{
        printf("started loop");
        fscanf(f, "%d", temp[0]);
        printf("%d \n", temp[0]);
        image->rgbdata[counter].r = temp[0];
        fscanf(f, "%d", temp[0]);
        image->rgbdata[counter].g = temp[0];
        fscanf(f, "%d", temp[0]);
        image->rgbdata[counter].b = temp[0];
    }while(1);
```

Comment: `fscanf(f, "%d", temp[0])` should be `fscanf(f, "%d", &temp[0])`

Comment: Why is `temp` an array if you only ever use `temp[0]`? Why don't you scan directly into the array members like `fscanf(f, "%d", &image->rgbdata[counter].r);`

Comment: I thought I had tried Barmars solution and it still had the seg fault, but retyped it and now works perfect, thanks

Comment: the OPs posted code does not compile.  Amongst other reasons, it is missing the needed `#include` statements for the  needed header files.  Please post a [mcve] so we can reproduce the problem and help you debug it.

Comment: OT: regarding: `image = (PPM *)malloc(sizeof(PPM));`  1) in C, the returned type is `void*` which can be assigned to any pointer.  Casting just clutters the code.  2)  the operation can fail, so always check (!=NULL) the returned value to assure the operation was successful.

Comment: Yes, I excluded parts of the program from this post which weren't relevant, I have the needed include files and it compiles and records the rgb values as required using Barmars solution. Thanks for the other tips